# It is possible to create multiple conditions for the same CloudWatch alarm for AutoScaling group with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

This is my resource and I need it to follow 2 conditions:

## ASG min size > threshold

## ASG min size < threshold

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "GroupMinSize" {
  count               = 1
  alarm_name          = "Autoscaling_Group_Min_Size"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "2"
  metric_name         = "GroupMinSize"
  namespace           = "AWS/AutoScaling"
  statistic           = "Minimum"
  period              = "120"
  threshold           = 1

  dimensions = {
    AutoScalingGroupName = aws_autoscaling_group.asg[count.index].name
  }

  alarm_description = "The minimum size of the Auto Scaling group"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to AWS cloudformation documentation, `comparison_operator` is a string, therefore you cannot have multiple conditions. If cloudformation cannot do it, Terraform cannot do it either.

```
ComparisonOperator
The arithmetic operation to use when comparing the specified statistic and threshold. The specified statistic value is used as the first operand.

You can specify the following values: GreaterThanThreshold, GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold, LessThanThreshold, or LessThanOrEqualToThreshold.

Required: Yes

Type: String

Allowed values: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold | GreaterThanThreshold | GreaterThanUpperThreshold | LessThanLowerOrGreaterThanUpperThreshold | LessThanLowerThreshold | LessThanOrEqualToThreshold | LessThanThreshold
```

However, you can combine multiple alarms to make a composite.

[Cloudformation-documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html)
[Terraform-documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm)